# Groovy : how do you create unique combination arrays from arrays?

Tags: arrays, grails, groovy

I would like to find a quick simple way to create unique array combinations from existing array values.

Lets say I have 2 arrays.

**Array 1**

```
[1, 5, 10]
```

**Array 2**

```
[2, 3]
```

I would like to create unique combination arrays from both arrays.

**Desired output**

```
[1, 2], [5, 2], [10, 2], [3, 1], [3, 5], [3, 10]
```

Besides iterating over each array and creating arrays, is there a better way to approach this?  Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance for any guidance provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the combinations method of GroovyCollections. See
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#combinations(java.lang.Iterable)

```
combinations([[true, false], [true, false]])
```

yields

```
[[true, true], [false, true], [true, false], [false, false]]
```

Comment: I just called combinations() method on the array of arrays and it worked as desired.  Thank you